# PHP count the enabled value variables from an array

Tags: php, count

I have an array of values that can be DISABLED or ENABLED, so I want to know how many are there ENABLED. Here is a piece of code:

```
$list = array(
$variable1,
$variable2,
$variable3,
$variable4
);
$count = count($list);
```

Thanks for any reply.

UPDATE: the values are NOT true and or false but ENABLE / DISABLE. Do your answers apply in this case? Thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the only valid options are boolean TRUE and FALSE, then

```
$countTrue = array_sum($list);
```

**EDIT**

with 'ENABLE' and 'DISABLE' as the possible values:

```
$countTrue = array_reduce(
    $list,
    function($counter, $value) {
        return $counter + ($value == 'ENABLE');
    },
    0
);
```

Comment: + nice type conversion hack

Comment: Nice one. Too bad OP changed the meaning of the question though.

Comment: Thank you Mark, best beer for you :)

Comment: I have to disagree with the array_sum() effort - It certainly works and is a very terse line of code. But this code will cause confusion for other coders (or even you when you look at it in 6 months time.) It's going to need a comment explaining the "nice type conversion **hack**" - @baba The solution provided by yourself is much clearer as it uses fit for purpose functions. - anyway, just my $0.02.

Comment: @webarto they are both fine, first is when considering the variables being true or false, second (or the edit) considering that variable values are enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 9):

Just use `array_filter`

```
$list = array(true,false,true,true);
$count = count(array_filter($list));
echo $count ;
```

Or

```
$list = array("Enable","DISABLE","ENabLE","ENABLE");
$count = count(array_filter($list,function($v) { return stripos($v, "enable") !== false; } ));
echo $count ;
```

`ENABLE` and `DISABLE` are long string but they start with `E` & `D` respectively you can use that for counting

```
$count = array_reduce($list,function($a,$b){$b{0} == "E" and $a++ ;return $a;},0);
echo $count ;
```

They Would all output

```
3
```

Comment: Much cleaner solution than others have suggested (myself included). votes++

Comment: What will this output:

    $count = count(array_filter($list, 'enabled'));

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array('ENABLED', 'DISABLED', 'ENABLED', 'ENABLED', 'ENABLED', 'DISABLED');
$count = array_count_values($array);
```

would produce

```
array(2) {
  ["ENABLED"]=>int(4)
  ["DISABLED"]=>int(2)
}
```

so you can call it using

```
$count["ENABLED"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the array and count them.

```
$trueValues = 0;
foreach ($list as $listItem)
{ 
  if ($listItem)
    $trueValues++;
}

echo "Array has ".$trueValues." TRUE items);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = array('ENABLE','DISABLE','ENABLE','ENABLE');   

function countTrues($n)
{
    if ($n == 'ENABLE'){return $n;}
}

$x = array_filter($list , "countTrues");

$count =  count($x);
```

This should do the trick